# Do we keep reflexibility functional dependency in minimal cover

Tags: functional-dependencies, database-theory

Assume I have to come up the minimal cover of a set of functional dependencies. I have this functional dependency `{A,B,C} -> {C}`. We would know that `{A,B}` is redundant and we should remove these two attribute to get the minimal cover. This will leave us with `{C} -> {C}`, but this is trivial due to reflexibility. Do we still retain `{C} -> {C}` or remove it as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Any dependency of the form:

```
X → Y
```

where Y ⊆ X (Y is a subset of X),  is called a “trivial dependency”, and is always true by definition. So, it should be removed from the minimal cover. Formally, it is removed in the third step of the algorithm that produces a minimal cover, where redundant dependencies are eliminated.